# how to display data with the same attribute value on laravel

Tags: laravel

My Table

| user_number | user_name | events | register_date |

001
                  ....
           E01
     01-01-2017

002
                  ....
           E01
     01-01-2018

001
                  ....
           E02
     01-01-2017

002
                  ....
           E02
     01-01-2018

001
                  ....
           E02
     01-03-2018

I want to display user number where user number and date of register are the same and more than one, where in the above cases are 001 --- 01-01-2017 and 002 --- 01-01-2018

how to query it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy()` and `havingRaw`:

```
$records = DB::table('my_table')
             ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->groupBy('user_number', 'events')
             ->havingRaw('total > 1')
             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to print all rows available for userdetail

`$data= ModelName::select('*')->get();`

> In your view(Blade File)

`@foreach ($data as $user)
   {{$user->user_number}}<p> --- </p>{{$user->register_date}}<br>
@endforeach`

> Result will be:

001 --- 01-01-2017
002 --- 01-01-2018

Answer (score 0):

> Try This.....

```
DB::table('table_name')
->where(['user_number'=>'001', 'register_date'=>'01-01-2017'])
->orWhere(['user_number'=>'002', 'register_date'=>'01-01-2018'])
->get();
```